# How can i push values of a specific field with mongoose aggregate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using this code inside a route:

```
    MyModel.aggregate(
        [
            { "$group": { 
                    "_id": "$date",
                    "participants": { "$sum": "$participants" },
                    "peoples": { $sum: 1 }
                } 
            },
        ],
         function(err, result) {
           console.log(result)
         }
  ......etc......
```

This is aggregating the date, participants and peoples, but i want access the name field, and i was trying like this:

```
"_id": "$date",
"name": "$name",
"participants": { "$sum": "$participants" },
"peoples": { $sum: 1 }
```

but is returning:

```
{ [MongoError: exception: the group aggregate field 'name' must be defined as an expression inside an object]
  name: 'MongoError',
  errmsg: 'exception: the group aggregate field \'some\' must be defined as an expression inside an object',
  code: 15951,
  ok: 0 }
```

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator for this. ie.:

```js
MyModel.aggreagate(
    [
        { "$group": {
            "_id": "$date",
            "name": { "$first": "$name" },
            "participants": { "$sum": "$participants" }, 
            "peoples": { "$sum": 1 }
        },
    ],
    function(err,results) { 
        // rest of processing.
    }
);
```

Suspect that your "peoples" and "participants" fields are also wrong. But that's another question out of context here.

Comment: I don't think so, the 'participants'  is the sum of the participants with the same _id , and the people is the sum of outputs with the same _id. I am right?